# App permission in flutter - "Allow Display over other apps"

Tags: android, flutter, plugins, flutter-dependencies, appsettings

**My expectation:**

I want to open app settings to allow permission for "allow display over other apps". So, when I click on the button in my app, then directly "allow display over other apps" setting screen should get open. Below I've attached a sample screen which i'm expecting to get open:

Allow_display_screen:

[image]

**Problem:**

But that screen (allow_display) is not opening directly, the complete app settings get open. Below is the attached screenshot for refrence:

App_settings_screen:

[image]

**Mycode:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_settings/app_settings.dart';

class CheckApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CheckApp> createState() => _CheckAppState();
}

class _CheckAppState extends State<CheckApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('App Settings'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: const Text("App Settings"),
              onTap: () => AppSettings.openAppSettings(
                  type: AppSettingsType.settings, asAnotherTask: true),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

**What I did:**

I've used [app_settings_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings) but it doesn't provide such funcionality to directly open that screen (allow_display).

**Query:** Is there any different plugin to do so ? or, by making some changes in code this can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

You have display inside the [AppSettingsType](https://github.com/spencerccf/app_settings/blob/e0c5b98b96c55dafe7212ef02a9ff15e09e495f4/lib/src/app_settings_type.dart#L4). So please try this for onTap:

`onTap: () => AppSettings.openAppSettings(type: AppSettingsType.display, asAnotherTask: true),`

Comment: I tried this earlier as well but it's opening a different screen, which shows display screen for the device not of the app as i'm expecting.